# Extracting subtitles from mp4

Tags: mp4, video-processing, subtitle

I got an assignment of retrieving subtitles from a mp4 file

I want to know how to do this, by java or c++, does it depends on mp4 encoding format and

I want to know the basic concepts of different video formats and basic concepts of video processing.

Comment: http://www.ffmpeg.org/

Comment: found mp4 parser, but can't find the exact API for operating on subtitles

Answer (score 14):

there is several subtitle format, SRT, STL(mainly use by Apple), etc.... and ffmpeg support a lot of them http://ffmpeg.org/general.html#Subtitle-Formats

and ffmpeg can extract them with cmd line the following sequence of command:

1) perform track identification

```
ffmpeg -i yourFile
```

2) extract the subtitle track with

```
ffmpeg -i yourFile -vn -an -codec:s:X.Y srt 
sub.srt
```

with X.Y the track number indicator you found from the cmd (1) .

Answer (score 12):

Neither of the other answers here worked for me with an `m.m4v` containing multiple subtitles. But the following did work (with both .m4v and .mp4 files):

```
ffmpeg -i m.m4v -map 0:s:0 eng.srt
ffmpeg -i m.m4v -map 0:s:1 ita.srt
ffmpeg -i m.m4v -map 0:s:2 fre.srt
```

In my `m.m4v` are 3 subtitle streams with English being the first, Italian the second, French the third. It appears to be the order that's used for the ffmpeg command rather than the `X.Y` (input.stream) values one obtains with `ffmpeg -i m.m4v`

which for my `m.m4v` gave:

```
Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
Stream #0:3(ita): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
Stream #0:4(fre): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
```

I'm using Mac OS 10.4.5 on a Macbook Pro 2015

By the way, if there's only one subtitle track then you would use:

```
ffmpeg -i m.m4v -map 0:s:0 sub.srt
```

Answer (score 3):

> ffmpeg -i yourFile -map X:Y srt sub.srt

extract only needed track

Answer (score 0):

updated the code to v5 ver.

work pretty good.

usage:

ffmpegSubExtract mp4 srt

ffmpegSubExtract mp4 srt 1

```
@echo off
cls

if "%1"=="" (
echo.
echo Usage:
echo ffmpegSubExtract mp4 srt
echo ffmpegSubExtract mp4 srt 1
goto :eof )

if "%2"=="" (
echo.
echo Usage:
echo ffmpegSubExtract mp4 srt
echo ffmpegSubExtract mp4 srt 1
goto :eof )

set fle=%1
set ext=%2
set str=%3

for %%i in ("*.%fle%") do (set fname=%%i) & call :rename
goto :eof

:rename
if exist "%fname:~0,-4%.%ext%" (
    del "%fname:~0,-4%.%ext%" )

if "%str%"=="" (
    set str=0 )


if "%ext%" == "srt" (
    ffmpeg -i "%fname%" -map 0:s:%str% "%fname:~0,-4%.%ext%"
) else (
    ffmpeg -i "%fname%" -c copy -map 0:s:%str% "%fname:~0,-4%.%ext%" 
)

goto :eof

rem come code from here
rem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388253/extracting-subtitles-from-mp4
rem https://superuser.com/questions/583393/how-to-extract-subtitle-from-video-using-ffmpeg
```