# Best method for extracting(or reading) subtitles from MP4 File in C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

i got a problem that i have to read subtitles from MP4 files

current i using command line with ffmpeg executable method.
[Extracting subtitles from mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388253/extracting-subtitles-from-mp4)
it's worked great, but looking for better method.

after several research
i try to use AForge.NET, other FFMpeg .Net Wrapper, direct access MP4 structure, etc...
but didn't work

anyone knows other way for extracting or reading subtitles from MP4?
thank for your help.